# Placing the abstract on titlepage in custom class

Tags: titles, package-writing, abstract

Imagine I want to include my abstract to my titlepage. I would do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,english,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{Last update: \today}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
  \hrule

  \vfill

  \begin{center}
    {\huge \sffamily \@title} \\[3em]

    {\itshape \@author}
  \end{center}

  \vskip 5em

  \begin{abstract}
    Abstaction is the abstract process of making things abstract.
  \end{abstract}

  \vfill

  \hrule 
  \begin{center}
    \itshape \@date
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Now suppose I really like my layout, so much that I want to make it a class/package. My problem is that the user must be able to write the abstract without worrying about the layout, but I (the developper of the class) don't have anything to *call the abstract*: I miss something like `\@abstract`. Of course, my package could contains something as:

```latex
\newcommand{\myabsract}[1]{\def\@mysabstract{#1}}
```

And I would be able to call the content of `\@myabstract` wherever I want, but the user then has to write:

```latex
\myabstract{Abstraction is the abstract process of making things abstract.}
```

instead of using the usual abstract environment. Is there a *clean way* to do what I want (maybe by redefining the abstract environment)?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution using TeX boxes:

```
\newbox\@abstractbox
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \global\setbox\@abstractbox=\vbox\bgroup
  \noindent\unskip\textbf{\abstractname}
  \par\medskip\noindent\unskip\ignorespaces}
{\egroup}
```

(If something seems off, please signal it in the comments.)